# Add class to item with the same number

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do you add a class to an item with the same number?

```
    <div class="button1"></div>
    <div class="button2"></div>
    <div class="button3"></div>

    <div class="hidden panel1"><div>
    <div class="hidden panel2"><div>
    <div class="hidden panel3"><div>

    // something to the effect of 
    <script>
       $('.button[n]').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(('.hidden[n]').addClass('active');
       });
    </script>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<div class="button1 btnclick" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="button2 btnclick" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="button3 btnclick" data-id="3"></div>


<div class="hidden panel1"><div>
<div class="hidden panel2"><div>
<div class="hidden panel3"><div>



// something to the effect of 
    <script>
       $('.btnclick').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).data('id');
          $(('.panel'+id).addClass('active');
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `data-*` corresponding to the class of the div.
2. Use the `data-*` to tell which class is to be selected.
3. Use `^` starting selector

[attribute-starts-with-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```js
$('[class^=button]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.hidden').removeClass('active');
  var panel = $(this).attr('data-panel');
  $('.'+panel).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button1" data-panel="panel1">1</div>
<div class="button2" data-panel="panel2">2</div>
<div class="button3" data-panel="panel3">3</div>

<div class="hidden panel1">1
</div>
<div class="hidden panel2">2
</div>
<div class="hidden panel3">3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/udoarexb/

```js
$('div.btn').click(function(){
  $('div.panel' + $(this).index())
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings('div.hidden')
    .removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn button1">Button 1</div>
<div class="btn button2">Button 2</div>
<div class="btn button3">Button 3</div>

<div class="hidden panel1">Panel 1</div>
<div class="hidden panel2">Panel 2</div>
<div class="hidden panel3">Panel 3</div>
```

I've added an extra class to button class as `btn`.

**Another solution without adding adding any extra attribute in HTML**
Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/udoarexb/1/

```js
$('div[class^=button]').click(function(){
 var num = $(this).attr('class');
  num = num.replace(/\D/g, '');
 num = parseInt(num, 10);
  $('div.panel' + num).addClass('active').siblings('div.hidden').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button1">Button 1</div>
<div class="button2">Button 2</div>
<div class="button3">Button 3</div>

<div class="hidden panel1">Panel 1</div>
<div class="hidden panel2">Panel 2</div>
<div class="hidden panel3">Panel 3</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what if the order changes?

Comment: I believe if the order will changes, then it will change in both the places and it will work.

Comment: `I believe` your assumption might be different from the OP's

Comment: @guradio. I may be very rude (but I'm sorry). Even i your suggestion you are adding exta `data attribute`. That also you are assuming correct. Scenario may `HTML`  is not static & the OP can't change the `HTML` structure by adding data attribute. I believe, everyone is having some assumption & providing solution. Again I'm sorry for being rude.